# Comment out an item in table on haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, haml

You have a table on haml.

```
  %table
    %tr
      %th HOGE1
      %th HOGE2
      %tr
        %td HAGE1
        %td HAGE2
```

Now you want to comment out the first item.

```
      %table
        %tr
-#          %th HOGE1
          %th HOGE2
          %tr
-#            %td HAGE1
            %td HAGE2
```

...

WHY IT DOESN'T WORK.....?

Comment: There should not be spaces between `-#` and `%th`

Comment: Your comment should be indented to the level of your code as haml works on indentation

Comment: Thank you for advises.  That completely blew my agony away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should not be spaces between -# and %th
try:

```
%table
  %tr
    -#%th HOGE1
    %th HOGE2
  %tr
    -#%td HAGE1
    %td HAGE2
```

Output html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>HOGE2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HAGE2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`#-` will omit corresponding line.
`/` will comment out the line and generate html comment

```
%table
  %tr
    /%th HOGE1
    %th HOGE2
  %tr
    / %td HAGE1
    %td HAGE2
```

Output html :
`<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- %th HOGE1 -->
    <th>HOGE2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- %td HAGE1 -->
    <td>HAGE2</td>
  </tr>
</table>`